# Check if $P^{NP} = P^{coNP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, oracle-machines

> Check if $P^{NP} = P^{coNP}$

To my eye answer is "unknown".
I would try to show that it implies that $coNP=NP$, what is unknown fact.

Lets suppose that $P^{NP} = P^{coNP}$. Then we use simply deterministic turing machine $M\in PTIME$ which use oracle. Lets launch both oracles on the same arbitrary instance. It is moment in which I don't know how to continue. Can you help me?, please ?

Comment: They are equal: $\mathsf P$ can negate any bit it received from oracle.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you be more precisely ?

Comment: If you can solve problem with SAT oracle, then you also can solve it with UNSAT oracle, just replacing `SAT(f)` with `~UNSAT(f)`. This is allowed.

Comment: Yes, all right. However, in case of $NP^{NP}  = NP^{coNP}$ it is more complex. Could you attach more details and explain where is the crux of difference ?

Comment: @rus9384 Please post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @ComplexityFun, this is quite another question.

Comment: We can tell it's you even if you slightly change your name. You are abusing this site.

Answer (score 0):

Classes $\mathsf{P^{NP}}$ and $\mathsf{P^{coNP}}$ are equal.

Maybe it's not good example (because it is functional problem), but let's look at optimization version of TSP.

It asks *what is the length of the shortest cycle that passes through all vertices?* It is $\mathsf{FP^{NP}}$-complete.

To solve it, we'll use decision TSP oracle which answers *is there a cycle that passes through all vertices of length $\leq k$.* It is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

Algorithm works as follows:

1. Choose some starting number $p$. We can use greedy solution for this.
2. Ask TSP oracle if there is a cycle of length $p/2$.

   1. If 'no', ask if there exists a cycle of length $3p/4$.
   2. If 'yes', ask if there exists a cycle of length $p/4$.
3. Continue binary searching until length of shortest cycle is found.

Now to show that TSP optimization is also in $\mathsf{P^{coNP}}$, I'll modify algorithm. It will use now coTSP decision oracle which answers *if there is no cycle that passes through all vertices of length $\leq k$*.

Now modification of algorithm:

1. Choose some starting number $p$. We can use greedy solution for this.
2. Ask TSP oracle if there is no cycle of length $p/2$.

   1. If 'yes' (there is no cycle), ask if there exists a cycle of length $3p/4$.
   2. If 'no', ask if there exists a cycle of length $p/4$.
3. Continue binary searching until length of shortest cycle is found.

So, this shows that $\mathsf{P^{NP}=P^{coNP}}$ (because equality between functional classes implies equality between decision classes).

Edit: confused path and cycle.